# how to prevent Windows OS password resetting methods e.g. utilman.exe

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, command-line, windows-8, security

I came here because topic is serious about my windows system, here is last day somehow I abled to reset my windows password by doing..
This Windows Commands

**Using bootable Windows OS Open Commands Prompts**

> C:\windows\System32>copy utilman.exe utilman.exe
>
> C:\windows\System32>copy cmd.exe cmd1.exe
>
> C:\windows\System32>del utilman.exe
>
> C:\windows\System32>rename cmd.exe utilman.exe

after system came to **Real Mode**

> C:\windows\System32>control userpasswords

its open a window where you able to reset your password..
okay this steps done my job nicely..
but what about my security when I away from system, in time how can I protect my systems?.

Comment: The described method can be prevented by using BitLocker.

Comment: Short answer: You can't. Bear in mind that when anyone has unattended access to your computer all bets are off - with the possible exception of your encrypting your drives with bitlocker as that is impossible to crack AFAIK.

Comment: And perhaps some government agency, with sufficient resources, could crack even that. As @DavidPostill states, if there is physical access, there is no *guaranteed* way to prevent access. One example: a penetration tester masqueraded as a fireman inspecting electric cords on PC's and installed key loggers...